# How does one add a hyperlink in a microsoft form?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have made a quick web search and found no way of inserting simple links in (such as web addresses) in Office Forms.

What she does in [this 30 secs video](https://youtu.be/8IENJeBmmHE) does not work for me: example.com and https://example.com are not recognized as links. Here is the preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a hyperlink, add the <> symbols surrounding your full link (for example) https://yourfulllink.com - when you click out of the field it will appear a link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this bot is not good

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the title to allow editing.
  [image: Edit Form title and description]
- Enter the web address on the description field
  [image: Description field with web address]
- Preview the form. The link can be clicked to open the web address
  [image: Clickable link on the form]

Comment: This does not work for me :(

Comment: @Sam What part does not work? What is the output/result when you follow the steps?

Comment: I edited the question with some more info